# GDAL where clause failing

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr, where-clause

I have written an ogr2ogr script to convert well known text values into reprojected geometry table, however even when excluding values with the value "NULL" (as opposed to no value at all) it still thinks there are NULLs, with the SQL error `The label NULL in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON and FULLGLOBE (geography Data Type only).`

I assume my GDAL syntax is incorrect for the where clause.

```
pushd \\gisdataserver\data\ogr2ogr

ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" -s_srs "EPSG:4283" 
"MSSQL:server=blah;database=blah;trusted_connection=yes" 
"MSSQL:server=blah;database=blah;trusted_connection=yes" -sql "SELECT rowguid, 
geometry::STGeomFromText(tk_geomWKT,0) GEOMETRY_SPA FROM Assets_Nextgen.dbo.blah" -where 
"\"tk_geomWKT\" <> \"NULL\"" -t_srs "EPSG:28355" -spat_srs "EPSG:28355" -lco 
"GEOM_TYPE=geometry" -lco "GEOM_NAME=GEOMETRY_SPA" -nln "blah"

popd \\gisdataserver\data\ogr2ogr
```

Comment: I am not sure if -sql and -where are meant to be used together. -where is obviously an older option and more flexible -sql has been added later. Drop -where and enhance your -sql.

Comment: Thanks. I did have the where clause within but was still getting errors. Does the where clause still need to escape quotes as it is surrounded by quotes?

Comment: Test your query with your normal MS-SQL client first. In SQL `"NULL"` means the value of field named NULL, while `'NULL'` means a string. But yes, if you need double quotes in the SQL statement you must escape them.

Comment: "SELECT rowguid, geometry::STGeomFromText(tk_geomWKT,0) GEOMETRY_SPA FROM Assets_Nextgen.dbo.Task where tk_geomWKT <> 'NULL'" gives the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare to `NULL`s so you need to use `tk_geomWKT is not NULL` instead. See this [page](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-filter-rows-without-null-in-a-column/) for more details, or for a longer and fuller discussion of why you can't do this see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078837/why-doesnt-sql-support-null-instead-of-is-null).

If, however, you have an actual string NULL you need to enclose it in `'` single quotes, `tk_geomWKT != 'NULL'`.

Comment: I understand that. The data has the word NULL, as opposed to an empty field.